# How do I add a VMware ESXi Host to Microsoft Virtual Machine Manager?

Tags: vmware-esxi, scvmm

I am trying to manage virtual machines running on a VMware ESXi host using Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager.

I was able to add the ESXi machine using the "Add VMware VirtualCenter server" option, but can't access any of the VMs on the datastore associated with this ESXi server.

The datastore of the ESXi box is showing up with the correct name, but it won't let me see any of the VMs that have already been created; I get "There are no virtual machines on this host."

Because I couldn't get any of the existing virtual machines to show up, I tried creating some new ones. When using VMM to connect to ESXi and create new VMs, I get the following error messages in the "rating explanation" section:

> The virtualization software on the
>   selected host does not support virtual
>   hard disks on an IDE bus.

and

> The virtualization software on the
>   host XXXXXX does not support the
>   creation of dynamic virtual hard disk.

Any ideas on why I can't manage existing machines and why I can't create new ones? The existing machines were created in vSphere.

I should note that the ESXi server and the server running SCVMM are both on the same domain.

I should also note that although the ESXi box has been added as a VirtualCetner server, when I try to add it through the "Add Host" option, I get an error message saying "Virtual Machine Manager cannot complete the VirtualCenter action on server ESXi because of the following error: The operation is not supported on the object."

Answer (score 1):

vCenter is a management tool installed on either a physical or virtual Windows 2003 or 2008 server. vCenter in turn manages ESX and ESXi hosts/clusters.

It sounds like you're trying to directly add an ESX or ESXi server when in fact its meant to communicate with a "vCenter" server.

Comment: Also, the SCVMM may be trying to use the vsphere API's which are very similar regardless of whether or not you're connecting directly to ESX or connecting to a vCenter, so perhaps that is why some things work. It sounds like you need to install vCenter on a dedicate box or VM first and point SCVMM at that.

Comment: Also, according to this page, it appears they only support older versions of ESX(i) and vCenter. Check your compatibility lists. http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/virtual-machine-manager/vmm-system-requirements-r2.aspx

Answer (score -1):

ESX does not support using IDE hard disk. What you need to do is to add a new SCSI adapter in the VM creation wizard and attach the virtual hard disk to this controller.